# How to setup htaccess to show new posts on WP site?

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, cache-control

I'm using VPS CentOS + Apache + Wordpress. Not using any Cache plugin but htaccess instead. All work good except my home page wont refresh if I write new post. Only new visitors can see new posts.
This is htaccess I currently use. Please take a look and give me advice. Let's say to refresh homepage every 1 hour?

```
#Force WWW + SSL
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
#RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# Compress text, html, javascript, css, xml
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 7200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 7200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 7200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 7200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 7200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 7200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 7200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 7200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>

# 480 weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|svg)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 2 DAYS
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# 2 HOURS
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

FileETag None

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Disable server signature
ServerSignature Off
```

Comment: Have you confirmed in the network traffic (browser tools > network tab) that this is indeed a client-side caching issue? What mime-type is your server responding with for HTML pages (I would assume `text/html` - but to be sure)? Add the HTTP response headers to your question. Your "caching" directives already state a 10 minute cache time (considerably less than your "1 hour" goal), so this would seem to be OK (there are often other things, like cookies that can break the cache anyway). "Won't refresh" - you mean when you hit F5 or Ctrl+F5?

Comment: You don't generally need both mod_expires (`ExpiresByType`) and mod_headers (`Header set Cache-Control`) - these are doing the same thing.

Comment: I will refresh if I hit F5. If I visit my site incognito mode I'll get fresh content. It won't refresh if I visit site now, and once again for about 5-6 hours (if post has been published in between)

Comment: "Add the HTTP response headers to your question." - when in _incognito mode_.

Comment: @w3dk can you please show me how to add HTTP response. I don't really know much about this. It is my first time dealing with VPS and apache. I have live site with good google position and now I'm worry not to lose that.

Thank you